# How to pull logs from Unix boxes to my local machine?

Tags: unix, logging, local

I deploy applications to  Unix boxes, we will work on around 100 boxes and lets say application A will be deployed on 5 boxes like Box1,Box2,Box3,Box4,Box5, Every time we deploy an application A we will go to each Box1,2,3,4,5 and check whether the application A which i s deployed has started properly or not in the path of BOX1/A/B/C/logs folder on each and every box and for every single application.

Is there a way we can pull the logs to local from all the Boxes 1,2,3,4,5 and it should allow me to Search the logs by Application A name.

Thanks for your help in advance ...

Comment: Yes there is, there are many ways.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried using Splunk but my company is not ready to buy the licenses for that, They are looking some thing which should not cost them.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, your question is not so specific that I can tell you exactly what to do in your particular case, but something very like this will nonetheless aggregate the data on your local stdout, after which you can process it locally as you like:

```
for I in $(seq 1 5); do echo "box$I:"; ssh username@box$I 'cat /var/log/mylog'; echo; done
```

Many variations on the theme are possible, but if you can get this one to work, then you should soon be able to see how to adapt it to your own need.

Note that, for Ssh to do its work without requiring a manual login on each machine requires some setup on both the local and remote boxes:  `man 1 ssh` and review the AUTHENTICATION section, especially the paragraph that speaks of the `authorized_keys` file.